# How to delete data from MySQL using a php page?

Tags: php, mysql, command

I am creating a Quiz website that has 2 sections, 1 for the user and 1 for the admin. The admin section is where the admin can view, add, edit or delete a question. I have this delete command and I have linked it to the 'delete' option in my table but it doesn't work. here's my code:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

    mysqli_query("DELETE FROM tblAssignment2 WHERE question_id = $_GET[question]") or die(mysqli_error());
    echo "Question has been deleted!";
    header('location: admin.php');

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Have you seen any errors? Can you tell us what those errors are? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Wide open to sql injection

Comment: You need to change `$_GET[question]` to `$_GET['question']`

Comment: Sidenote: `or die(mysqli_error($con))` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php `string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )`

Comment: Yikes yikes yikes! I sure hope nobody passes in "0 OR 1=1" as question!

Comment: `You need to change $_GET[question] to $_GET['question']`........ At the very least he should probably change it to `$question_id = (int)$_GET['question'];`

Comment: I wish we all got a nickel (or your country's equivalent) every time there is a "it doesn't work" question

Comment: @JayBlanchard Now, why does [`that`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406161/how-to-delete-data-from-mysql-using-a-php-page#comment41460977_26406161) look familiar? lol

Comment: I have installed auto-complete on comments. I got tired of repeating yourself. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: [`mysqli_query($con,"DELETE...`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406161/how-to-delete-data-from-mysql-using-a-php-page#comment41461257_26406234) - Tutorials weren't effective I gather.

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your db/server totally destroyed.

Comment: *"`include 'connect.php';`"* - Please do, in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';
$_GET['question'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['question']);
mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM tblAssignment2 WHERE question_id = '".$_GET['question']."'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
//echo "Question has been deleted!"; // You don't need to echo because it will throw an error. With output buffering it wouldn't be displayed on the page.
header('location: admin.php');
exit(); // Exit.

?>
```

Comment: I don't like that `$_GET['question']` is still unescaped, but I'm glad that you addressed the echo statement

Comment: Usually its not unescaped in my codes i always handle the $_GET / $_POST stuff at first in a foreach and i am happy with that. Also i can unescape them anytime.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/cata15/public_html/assignment2/delete.php on line 5     

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/cata15/public_html/assignment2/delete.php on line 5      - this is the error

Comment: Ah you are using the Procedural style. i forgot about the link. Updated should work now.

Comment: [`Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406161/how-to-delete-data-from-mysql-using-a-php-page#comment41461011_26406161) @RamiPetros

Comment: Azarus how do i do that? sorry im not the best with these stuff :/ it's an assignment i gotta do. thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php for more details about mysqli functions and usage. You should read the docs before asking basic questions, thought.

Comment: [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) requires DB connection. Plus this `$_GET['question'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['question']);` why assigning the variable as `$_GET['question']`?

Comment: WOW, can my database be attack just with the information I provided? I am really sorry I took it down because I don't want to fail due to some attack! This is my university work guys I mean come on! I am just trying to get some help here not to get attacked!

Comment: Fred-ii yeah sorry i am just not using mysqli nowly. and i have my own methods to handle injections, xss, errors etc. :)

Comment: `$question = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['question']);
mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM tblAssignment2 WHERE question_id = '".$question."'")`

Comment: @RamiPetros - Since you haven't posted database connection credentials, no, your database can't be attacked from here. That being said, it's considered REALLY poor form to edit out anyone's answer (whether yours or another's). I know that the first introduction to security-related concepts can be pretty harsh, but that's because it's THAT important to get right. For some reading, I'm assigning [OWASP's PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: @RamiPetros University? Lordie, I didn't even go to "college". We're not "attacking" you, but really, c'mon... did you not read and understand the tutorials related to `mysqli`? I took time at the beginning when learning SQL to make sure I understood how it worked, including going through Stack's many questions and answers. Your question could have been avoided had you spent the time as many of us did and still do to write proper syntax.

Comment: *"`// You don't need to echo beause it will not be visible after the header location call`"* - Actually, that is output before header and would have thrown an `Headers already sent...` warning.

Comment: Wouldn't if he would use output buffering.

Comment: True, but it's usually better not to.

Comment: @RamiPetros I suggest you add more code to your question, including the form if you're using one and/or the method, also what you're using for DB connection, while replacing DB credentials with `xxx`. There's no way to know for certain, beyond what you've posted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete WHERE question_id then you need to make sure that $_GET is getting the question_id to be deleted and not the question